sorting with custom comparator but leaving unsorted if condition returns false
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> vect{
{"abc","def","2"},
{"def","ghi","2"},
{"abc","def","2"},
{"abc","def","3"}};
std::sort(vect.begin(),vect.end(),
[](const std::vector<std::string>& a,const std::vector<std::string>& b){
/*if(a[2]!=b[2]) return a[2]>b[2];*/});

What I want is preserving the initial order if their 2nd index element are same. More specifically, my expected result is
vect={
{"abc","def","3"},
{"abc","def","2"},
{"def","ghi","2"},
{"abc","def","2"}};

I want the element line with "3" to go up but the rest of the order to remain untouched. But it keeps auto-sorting according to indexes 0 and 1 too. (as if it's written like return a[2]!=b[2]?a[2]>b[2]:a[0]!=b[0]?a[0]<b[0]:a[1]<b[1]; it automatically adds an std::less-like continuation, thus keeps sorting remaining elements alphabetically) How to sort according to only index 2 values and not include some into sorting if their index 2 values are same?

Guessing a bit, but don't you just want a stable sort according to the last column (the number)?

I'm confused. How does what you want differ from a [standard] multikey sort? I think you may need to provide [many] more examples of input and expected output. It seems like you want to stop sorting after encountering a [false?] condition??? Is std::sort a stable sort? You may need to maintain some state info that stops the sort (i.e. always returns false after hitting the condition). Or, is it as simple as what alagner suggested?

Ah yes the std::stable_sort is indeed what I just need. Thank you very much and sorry for confusion. I had no idea how stable sorting worked.

C++20 ranges are quote handy and there is stable_sort too:
std::ranges::stable_sort(vect, std::greater<>{}, [](const auto& v) { return v[2]; });

Test: https://godbolt.org/z/rGP6Ern65
